# gunicorn worker exits for every request

Tags: python, gunicorn, airflow

I have a fresh installation of `apache-airflow 1.8.2`, started its webserver, and its gunicorn workers exit for every webpage request, leaving the request hang for around 30s while waiting for a new worker to spawn. Need help fixing this issue.

## Details below

I've installed `apache-airflow 1.8.2` and followed [this guide](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/start.html). I started the webserver at port `8081`.

Now when I visit the server using my browser, the response is very slow. I looked at the console output, and noticed that every time I load a webpage, it says "Worker existing", and then pauses for a long time and says "Booting worker".

After digging the source code I found out that these are gunicorn workers. I have no experience with gunicorn or airflow or Flask, so I don't know if this is the expected behavior, but I feel like it shouldn't. At least a webserver should not hang for half a minute for every webpage.

Console output:

```
---> Browser request
[2017-11-01 19:08:07 -0700] [14549] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14549)
---> Hangs for 30s
[2017-11-01 19:08:37 -0700] [13316] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2017-11-01 19:08:37 -0700] [14698] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14698
/Users/michael/Programs/clones/airflow/airflow/www/app.py:23: FlaskWTFDeprecationWarning: "flask_wtf.CsrfProtect" has been renamed to "CSRFProtect" and will be removed in 1.0.
  csrf = CsrfProtect()
/Users/michael/Programs/miaozhen/tests/airflow-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2017:19:08:37 -0700] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 95063 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
[2017-11-01 19:08:38,096] [14698] {models.py:168} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/michael/airflow/dags
---> other GET requests on the same webpage, skipped here for simplicity
[2017-11-01 19:08:39 -0700] [13316] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
```

Now I'm running a source version of `apache-airflow 1.8.2` (i.e. cloned the source, checked out the tag, and installed with `pip install -e .`) in a `virtualenv`. However I've also tried: running the pypi version (`pip install apache-airflow`) without `virtualenv`; running the source version without `virtualenv`. And the same problem exists for all installations, so these differences are irrelevant.

My Python installation is:

```
$ python -VV
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  4 2017, 06:09:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)]
```

EDIT:

I tried installing & running `apache-airflow` on another machine (Ubuntu Linux 16.04 + Python 3.5), and there is no problem. I also asked another person who is on Mac with Python 3.6, and there is no problem either. I guess there's something weird with my machine... Any suggestion how I can debug this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after debugging into source codes I managed to isolate the problem, however it has nothing to do with gunicorn.

The issue is [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175320/why-is-my-hostname-resolution-taking-so-long)

```
$ time python -c 'import socket; socket.getfqdn()'

real    0m30.051s
user    0m0.018s
sys     0m0.013s
```

I think the question should be closed as it's invalid now, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Workers regularly exiting from the signal `ttou` (means [decrement # of processes by one](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/signals.html#master-process)) every so often is intentional. This is airflow periodically "refreshing" workers. Based on what I read in [AIRFLOW-276](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-276), which added this feature, refreshing workers is to ensure they pickup on new or updated DAGs. This behavior can be modified in your airflow config under `worker_refresh_interval` and `worker_refresh_batch_size`.

From looking at the [source](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/bin/cli.py#L668-L680), it spins new workers up before spinning down old workers, so I don't think this would cause a delay for your requests. However, you can try disabling it with `worker_refresh_batch_size = 0`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried `worker_refresh_batch_size = 0`. It does disable workers from exiting and spawning, but there's still a ~30s delay after receiving the request. Also I've updated my question, please see that.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with airflow `1.10.1`, with the WUI being very unresponsive, and sure enough, calls to `socker.getfqdn()` were taking 10s of seconds.

I'm running inside an older version of Docker, which is known to have trouble when a container tries to resolve its own address via DNS.

As a workaround, I changed the configuration value `hostname_callable` in `airflow.cfg` to `socket:gethostname`, and the WUI proved responsive.

This does means the hostname used in all logs will be the local hostname (i.e. what you get when you run `hostname`).